# Javadoc doesn't match code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, javadoc

While refactoring, I messed up some of my `Javadoc` annotations through removing parameters, etc...

Is there some tool in Eclipse to find mismatches between the code and the Javadoc annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the compiler options either in general or for your specific project, go into the Javadoc preferences and you can tell the compiler to add warnings or errors for various problems with the Javadoc.